# Velocity Template Language dynamic variable

Tags: velocity, dynamic-variables, vtl

I read all of the [Velocity user guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html) and I don’t see how can acces to dynamic variable.

The Scenario:

```
#set ($u14 = "MARCOS SANCHEZ")
#set ($var = "u14")
```

How I Can acces to `$u14` with `$var`?

In php:

`$$var (vm fail)`

Result expected: `MARCOS SANCHEZ`

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what your goal is. Can you not directly access `$u14`?

Comment: Yes, but I dont know the u14. I recieve the number with another variable.

Comment: You know it because you set it. I think you need to post a better code

Comment: I #parse a constants file with 20 #set ($u14 = “MARCOS SANCHEZ”) like this.....and then I have a foreach of issues and i have the u14, u15,u16 number only... and I need the name of constant.

Comment: This is not possible using Template because can be done by Reflection only.But Most of the reflection methods are not acceptable in Velocity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [construct variable names dynamically in velocity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084542/construct-variable-names-dynamically-in-velocity)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58214273/470749 was the answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array or a map:

```
## initialize the map
#set($map = {})

## add an entry
$!map.put("u14", "MARCOS")

#set($var = "u14")

## retrieve the value
The value you are looking for is ${map.get($var)}
```

Something similar can be done with an [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123691/create-and-iterate-through-an-array-in-velocity-template-language). Also check the relevant section of the [VLT reference guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#set), which explains how to initialize a map or array. After initialization, you can call the methods described in the [java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) (get, put, etc.) from your velocity template.