# construct variable names dynamically in velocity

Tags: velocity

I would like to know if it is possible to construct name of variable into velocity dynamically.

i.e. lets say I've 6 variables into velocity template [name1, name2, name3 .. name6] I would like to output them.
So I'm looking in something like:

```
#foreach ( $counter in [1..6] )
${name${counter}}
#end
```

is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is possible using the [`#evaluate`](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#evaluate) directive:

```
#evaluate ('$name1')

#set ($d = '$')
#foreach ($i in [1..6])
  #set ($varName = "${d}name${i}")
  #evaluate($varName)
#end
```

Comment: @Sergiu Dumitriu How to put output of `evaluate` in a var?

Comment: @AamirAdnan `#set ($value = "#evaluate($varName)")` or, since you can evaluate any valid script: ```#set ($name1 = 'a1')
#set ($name2 = 'b2')
#set ($name3 = 'c3')
#set ($d = '$')
#set ($h = '#')
#foreach ($i in [1..3])
  #set ($expr = "${h}set (${d}value = ${d}name${i})")
  #evaluate($expr)
  $!value
#end
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58214273/470749 helped me understand.

Answer (score 6):

You could construct a map and build the names of the keys to retrieve the values you want:

```
#set( $map = {"${name}1":'value1', "${name}2":'value2'} )

#foreach ( $counter in [1..6] )
    #set( $key = "${name}$counter" )
    $map.get(${key})
#end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a trick to set velocity variable with dynamic name.

If you manage to tune velocity context beforehand in java code like this:

```
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext(paramsMap);
context.put("all", paramsMap);
```

then it would be possible to define dynamic vars in template like this:

```
#set($dynamicDef = "varName=varValue")
#set($dynamicName = $dynamicDef.substring(0, $dynamicDef.indexOf('=')))
#set($dynamicValue = $dynamicDef.substring($dynamicDef.indexOf('=')).substring(1))
## create var with dynamic name
$all.put($dynamicName, $dynamicValue)
```

and use them later like this:

```
#if ($varName)
varName=$varName ## prints varName=varValue
#end
```