# Dynamic Variables in Velocity

Tags: velocity, dynamic-variables

I've looked through a few answers here and I just quite can't get what I'm looking for, so maybe if I ask it specific to my situation:

First off, let me say that I am **very** new to Velocity, but I'm very proficient with PHP. I know we're comparing apples to oranges here, but just bear with me - just through the example.

Imagine this: I have some data in an array of objects that is fresh from the database. Within each record is a unique identifier. I want to use this unique identifier as a variable name in an object.

In PHP, this is stupid easy:

```
<?php

    $goalObject = new stdObject();

    foreach ($row as $data)
    {
        $identifier = $data->unique_id;            

        $goalObject->$$identifier = new stdObject();

        $goalObject->$$identifier->name = $data->name;
        $goalObject->$$identifier->total = $data->num_apples + $data->num_oranges;
    }
```

Notice the double sigil for `identifier` (*$$*).

Now, it's worth noting that the unique_id does indeed start with a letter, so it should be good for use as a variable name. An example unique_id would be something like AAA0000 or something to that effect. No spaces, no hyphens, no punctuation whatsoever.

So, my goal object would be `$goalObject->AAA0000->name` or `$goalObject->AAA0000->total`. (Or `$goalObject.AAA0000.name` and `$goalObject.AAA0000.total` in Velocity.)

If I could do something like that, I would be so happy. But from what I can tell, Velocity does not allow anything as cool as this.

Please, someone help me here.

Thank you in advance for any answers I may get.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of a recent post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084542/construct-variable-names-dynamically-in-velocity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [construct variable names dynamically in velocity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084542/construct-variable-names-dynamically-in-velocity)

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what I was looking for, but I managed to get this working using a map. I guess I just didn't fully understand what the other answers were saying. Normally, I would just delete this post and pretend it never happened, but there might be someone out there who has a similar problem.

In order to get `$goalObject.AAA0000.name` to work, I had to create a map.

```
#set($goalObject = {})

#foreach ($data in $row)
    #set($identifier = $data.unique_id)

    #set($name = $data.name)
    #set($total = $data.num_apples + $data.num_oranges)

    #set($dummy = $goalObject.put({
        'name'  : $name,
        'total' : $total
    }))
#end
```

This is working for me so far, but instead of typing `$goalObject.AAA0000.name`, I have to use `$goalObject.get("AAA0000").name`. I'm just happy that it's working.

Comment: $goalObject.AAA0000.name should work for you... you don't have to explicitly use .get() for retrieving map values