# How to construct dynamic variable NAMES?

Tags: velocity

I want to loop over data, and create dynamic maps that I can later push more data into. For example:

```
#foreach ($item in ["bob","john","andy"])
  #set(${item}_map = {})
#end
```

So that later I can do this:

```
$!bob_map.put("${foreach.count}", "${some_data}")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [construct variable names dynamically in velocity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084542/construct-variable-names-dynamically-in-velocity)

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
#foreach ($item in ["bob","john","andy"])
  <div id="${item}_map" ></div>
#end
```

So later you can do in JS:

```
<script>
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('bob_map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
}

</script>
```