# Initialize an array via Loop in Velocity

Tags: java, arrays, velocity, vtl

How can i convert this one into foreach loop in velocity?

```
#set($starArray5 = [])
#set($starArray4 = [])
#set($starArray3 = [])
#set($starArray2 = [])
#set($starArray1 = [])
```

I tried this one but it returns an error.

```
#foreach($i in [5..1])
  #set($starArray$i = [])
#end
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it returns an error ?? Please do specify error. Also, did you mention `#set($starArray2 = [])` twice by mistake?

Comment: Why don't you use an array of arrays instead?

Comment: @SabirKhan. it says error on the $i. and yes it was a mistake and I'll edit it.

Comment: @toKrause How can I do that on velocity?

Comment: @Lloydaaron: There are existing questions on SO about constructing dynamic variable names in velocity like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084542/construct-variable-names-dynamically-in-velocity) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33283748/how-to-construct-dynamic-variable-names). Not sure if those answer your question

Comment: @SabirKhan Thanks a lot!