# Using Dynamic Variables in Velocity Templates

Tags: velocity

I am using velocity templates to generate email templates and here I want to create tables for each 'tag' with respective values as table data.

I am passing a List tags with details of the tags including tagName, using which I am passing the respective List for each tag. (If tagName = "test", I am passing the data for the test table as $test)

As shown I have set the data of each table to $arrayobjs, but the table does not display the rows as I think it doesnt iterate through the $arrayobs. Please help me iterate through the data and set the data to the coloumns.

P.S.-Although I am able to print the value of $tags[0]
, $arrayobjs[0] does not print a value

```
    #set ($d = '$')                
        #foreach($tag in $tags)
        #set ($var = "${d}${tag.tagName}")
        #set ($arrayobjs = "#evaluate($var)")
            <table style='width:600px; padding-left: 11px; font:Segoe UI;'>
                <tr>
                    <td> <span style='font-size: 17px; font-weight: 400; font-family:Georgia;'>$tag.tagName </span></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <br>
                <table width=583 style='width:437.5pt; margin-left:8.25pt;border-collapse:collapse;font-family:"Segoe UI",sans-serif;'>
                    <tr  style='vertical-align:top;height:10px;'>

                        <td width=50px style='border:solid white 1.0pt;background: #a3a3c2;padding:1pt 1pt 1pt 1pt;'>
                            <p> <span style='font-size:10.0pt;color:#3d3d5c;'><b>COL1</b></span> <span style='font-size:9.0pt;color:#404040'> <br><b></b> </span> </p>
                        </td>
                        <td width=100px style='border:solid white 1.0pt;background: #a3a3c2;padding:1pt 1pt 1pt 1pt;'>
                            <p> <span style='font-size:10.0pt;color:#3d3d5c'><b>COL2</b></span> <span style='font-size:9.0pt;color:#404040'> <br><b></b> </span> </p>
                        </td>
                        <td width=50px style='border:solid white 1.0pt;background: #a3a3c2;padding:1pt 1pt 1pt 1pt;'>
                            <p> <span style='font-size:10.0pt;color:#3d3d5c'><b>COL3</b></span> <span style='font-size:9.0pt;color:#404040'> <br><b></b> </span> </p>
                        </td>
                        <td width=50px style='border:solid white 1.0pt;background: #a3a3c2;padding:1pt 1pt 1pt 1pt;'>
                            <p> <span style='font-size:10.0pt;color:#3d3d5c'><b>COL4</b></span> <span style='font-size:9.0pt;color:#404040'> <br><b></b> </span> </p>
                        </td>
                        <td width=50px style='border:solid white 1.0pt;background: #a3a3c2;padding:1pt 1pt 1pt 1pt;'>
                            <p> <span style='font-size:10.0pt;color:#3d3d5c'><b>COL5</b></span> <span style='font-size:9.0pt;color:#404040'> <br><b></b> </span> </p>
                        </td>
                        <td width=50px style='border:solid white 1.0pt;background: #a3a3c2;padding:1pt 1pt 1pt 1pt;'>
                            <p> <span style='font-size:10.0pt;color:#3d3d5c'><b>COL6</b></span> <span style='font-size:9.0pt;color:#404040'> <br><b></b> </span> </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    #foreach($o in $arrayobjs)
                    <tr  style='vertical-align:top;height:5px;'>
                        <td width=50px style='border:solid white 1.0pt;background: #f0f0f5;padding:0.5pt 0.5pt 0.5pt 0.5pt;'>
                            <p> <span style='font-size:9.0pt;color:#7F7F7F'></span> <span style='font-size:9.0pt;color:#404040'>$o.col1 </span> </p>
                        </td>
                        <td width=180px style='border:solid white 1.0pt;background: #f0f0f5;padding:0.5pt 0.5pt 0.5pt 0.5pt;'>
                            <p> <span style='font-size:9.0pt;color:#7F7F7F'></span> <span style='font-size:9.0pt;color:#404040'>$o.col2</span> </p>
                        </td>
                        <td width=30px style='border:solid white 1.0pt;background: #f0f0f5;padding:0.5pt 0.5pt 0.5pt 0.5pt;'>
                            <p> <span style='font-size:9.0pt;color:#7F7F7F'></span> <span style='font-size:9.0pt;color:#404040'>$o.col3</span> </p>
                        </td>
                        <td width=30px style='border:solid white 1.0pt;background: #f0f0f5;padding:0.5pt 0.5pt 0.5pt 0.5pt;'>
                            <p> <span style='font-size:9.0pt;color:#7F7F7F'></span> <span style='font-size:9.0pt;color:#404040'>$o.col4</span> </p>
                        </td>
                        <td width=30px style='border:solid white 1.0pt;background: #f0f0f5;padding:0.5pt 0.5pt 0.5pt 0.5pt;'>
                            <p> <span style='font-size:9.0pt;color:#7F7F7F'></span> <span style='font-size:9.0pt;color:#404040'>$o.col5</span> </p>
                        </td>
                        <td width=30px style='border:solid white 1.0pt;background: #f0f0f5;padding:0.5pt 0.5pt 0.5pt 0.5pt;'>
                            <p> <span style='font-size:9.0pt;color:#7F7F7F'></span> <span style='font-size:9.0pt;color:#404040'>$o.col6</span> </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    #end
                </table>
            #end
```

Comment: What is the output of `$arrayobjs` and `$arrayobjs.class.name`?

Comment: $arrayobjs outputs the complete list of objects.
$arrayobjs.class.name outputs String

Answer (score 3):

After almost 2 years I suggest the following answer :-)

```
#set ($d = '$')
#set ($h = '#')

#foreach($tag in $tags)
    #set ( $temp = "${h}set ( ${d}var = ${d}${tag.tagName} )" )
    #evaluate($temp)

    ## html code for table header

    #foreach($o in $var)
        ## table rows
    #end
#end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! P.S. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17107653/470749 also helped me understand.