# Velocity arrayList - adding values by index

Tags: arrays, arraylist, velocity

is the any way adding values to an arraylist at a certain position (index)?

The following code works fine (but add the element at the end of the array):

```
#set($arr = [])
#if ($arr.add('A')) #end
```

I also tried

```
#set($arr = [])
#if ($arr.add(1,'A')) #end
```

but that doesn't work. Although the Java class ArrayList does support both ways...
Any help highly appreciated.

BR,
Andreas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create and iterate through an array in Velocity Template Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123691/create-and-iterate-through-an-array-in-velocity-template-language)

Comment: Thx for referencing the other thread but I don't think it's the same. My request is about adding element to an array at a certain position (index).
I just wonder that it seems possible retrieving a value from an array based on the index with $arr.get($idx) but it seems not possible adding a value at a given position inside the array... Is this really the case?